# Set fancybox width from link rel attribute

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How would I retrieve a width setting on my a tag (e.g. in the REL attribute) and pass it to my jQuery fancybox function, so I can specify its width?  Here is my (pretty standard) Fancybox declaration:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //TODO - pass width/height value from link somehow
            $("a.popup").fancybox({
                'autoScale': false,
                'height': 500,
                'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                'type': 'iframe'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be overloading the `rel` attribute for this, that is not what it's for.

However, the code may look something like...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.popup").each(function() {
        var width = $(this).attr('rel');

        $(this).fancybox({
            'autoScale': false,
            'width': width,
            'height': 500,
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'type': 'iframe'
        });
    });
});
```